# Android Database - Passing Intent String into Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My app I'm working on is a collection of notes organized by Contacts. I am having a problem using the cursor to query the database for the correct rows of information. The main activity is a list of contacts based on the Contacts URI. Clicking a contact passes the Contact _ID as an intent string. I want to pass the string into the cursor to display only the rows where the contactId key matches the intent string, but every time I pass the string I get "NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer." I know the intent is going through because I created a menu item that makes a toast message with the intent string in it, which works fine every time, and the cursor works when hard coding the argument with an ID. I just cant figure out where the something is going wrong! I've only been working with Android for probably a week and a half, so it very well could be something very simple. Any help is greatly appreciated. My code is below.

This is the activity that should display the filtered rows of data:

```
public class NotesList extends ListActivity {
    public MyDbAdapter db;
    public String mIntentString, contactId;
    public int mIntentInt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = new MyDbAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        fillData();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mIntentString = extras.getString("contactId");
        contactId = extras.getString("contactId");
    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor mCursor = db.fetchNotesForContact(contactId);
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                mCursor,
                new String[] {MyDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, MyDbAdapter.KEY_DATETIME},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And this is the code for the cursor being called, and when changing the argument from "contactId" to say "139", that contacts' notes are returned:

```
public Cursor fetchNotesForContact(String contactId) {
    String[] columns = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_CONTACTID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATETIME};
    String projection = ("contactId = ?");
    String[] arguments = {contactId};
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, projection, arguments, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: what the data type of your contactId column

Comment: contactId is an integer. I had thought about changing it to a string but wasn't sure if there would be any repercussions because the ContactsContract.Contacts._ID is an integer. Not sure if it really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are calling `fillData()` method before contactId has its value. So its `null` in `fetchNotesForContact` as well.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db = new MyDbAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    //fillData(); move this
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mIntentString = extras.getString("contactId");
    contactId = extras.getString("contactId");
    fillData(); //to here
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. I'm still pretty new to programming so little things like this throw me off.

Comment: Beleave me... this kind of error has nothing to do with time of programming experience. This is a typical error where you are starring hours and hours onto your own code and just can't find out what's wrong. Then someone else entering the room and points directly at the wrong line. (Happens to me to often :-))